# please check out this SQL Server query,I can't figure out what wrong I have done

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT ls_inv_back.cli_no,   
     client.cli_name, 
 sum(  case when LS_INV_BACK.sell_price<=0.0 or LS_INV_BACK.sell_price is null or LS_INV_BACK.retail_price<=0 or LS_INV_BACK.retail_price is null 
           then 0.0
      case when left(product.prod_no,1)='3' and lower(product.monad)='kg' and  (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))>286  and  (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))<=1000 
           then  ls_inv_back.inv_num *100*convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(varchar(50),(Square(CEILING(((isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))/100- 0.01)/0.5)+1)+10000)))),4)) 
      case when left(product.prod_no,1)='3' and lower(product.monad)='kg' and  (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))>1000 and  (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))<=2000 
           then  ls_inv_back.inv_num * 100*convert(numeric(12,3), right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(varchar(50),(Square(CEILING((isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))/100- 10.01)+21)+10000)))),4)) 
      case when (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))=0 
           then 0.0
      case when  (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))>0.1 and   (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))<=10 
           then  ls_inv_back.inv_num *convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),Square(CEILING(((isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0) ) - 0.01)/0.5)+1)+10000))),4))
      case when  (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))>10  and   (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))<=20 
           then   ls_inv_back.inv_num *convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),Square(CEILING((isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0) ) - 10.01)+21)+10000))),4))
      case when  (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))>20  and   (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))<=50 
           then     ls_inv_back.inv_num *convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),(Square(CEILING((isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0) ) - 20.01)/2)+31)+10000)))),4))
      case when  (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))>50  and   (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))<=100 
           then    ls_inv_back.inv_num *convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),(Square(CEILING((isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0) ) - 50.01)/3)+46)+10000)))),4))
      case when  (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))>100  and   (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))<=286 
           then    ls_inv_back.inv_num *convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),(Square(CEILING((isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0) ) - 101.01)/5)+63)+10000)))),4))
     case when  (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))>286  and   (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))<=1366 
          then    ls_inv_back.inv_num *convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),(Square(CEILING((isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0) ) - 101.01)/5)+63)+100000)))),5))
     case when  (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))> 1366  and   (isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0))<=2000 
          then    ls_inv_back.inv_num *convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),(Square(CEILING((isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0) ) - 101.01)/5)+63)+1000000)))),6))
    else ls_inv_back.inv_num *isnull(LS_INV_BACK.sell_price,0) - isnull(LS_INV_BACK.retail_price,0)*60 end)     
FROM ls_inv_back,   
     client,
     product   
WHERE ( ls_inv_back.cli_no = client.cli_no ) and 
     ( ls_inv_back.prod_no = product.prod_no )   
group by ls_inv_back.cli_no,   
          client.cli_name
```

the error was:

> MSG 156，level 15，status 1，line 5  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'

in the second case syntax has error,however I can't figure it out what wrong I have done
thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need a `case` in front of every `when` block condition, only the first one.

Comment: thanks I'll try to fix it

Comment: If that still doesnt work, to narrrow doen exactly where the problem is, start with only 1 statement and add them in 1 at a time till you get the error, then you know the exact spot of the error.

Comment: thanks Brad,I'll try to fix it

Comment: thanks for your opinion  Random_User

Comment: You should also stop using implicit,comma separated joins. Instead switch to 'modern' `join...on` syntax. It's ANSI standard for 30-odd years!

Comment: Hey  HoneyBadger,I didn't use comma separated joins,It's multiplication symbols

Comment: Of course it's comma-delimited join syntax, but it's not 30 years old, just 26 :-)

Comment: No, you used implicit joins, like @HoneyBadger. He's talking about `FROM ls_inv_back,   
     client,
     product `. Consider having a read of [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: @Random_User `end)` is correct, the `)` is closing the `SUM(`

Comment: Hey Larnu I knew join syntax,however my sql statment try to multiplied by some numbers

Comment: Do be careful mixing case. Your table names are lower case but in your columns they are upper case. I would suggest using an alias to help shorten this quite a bit. This is a complicated query. Without some formatting and things to make this easier it will be very challenging to maintain this.

Comment: No, you used an implicit cross join and then turned them into an inner join with the where clause. It has nothing to do with multiplication.

Comment: thanks for your opinion  Sean Lange

Comment: When you remove the additional CASEs you'll get another error regarding the `RIGHT` function, you probably put `)` in a wrong position.

Comment: + dnoeth yeah I have noticed that issue thanks indeed

Comment: [ *60 end) ]   <<< should be [ *60) end ]  . I think that is your problem. Plus you just need the first CASE. Separate the other with WHEN. Give that a shot.

Comment: If you know `JOIN` syntax, then you have no excuse for why your `FROM` clause was written the way it was. :) On a different note, what I, SeanLange and HoneyBadger have expressed aren't opinions; it's advice (and good advice at that!). Implicit joins are incredibly frowned upon in this day and age and should be avoided at all costs. If you really are listing the tables (i.e. `FROM TableA A, TableB B...`) to create a Cartesian product then you should still be using `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: I have spent the last 20 minutes trying to format and have that query make sense. It is crazy. Why do you allow NULL for sell price or retail price? Just getting rid of those isnulls would be a couple hundred characters. When you convert a number to a string you don't need ltrim(rtrim(, there won't be any extra spaces. I think I might consider starting this over and finding ways to make it less complicated. Probably starting at the data model. Maintaining this query is going to be very painful.

Comment: @sdfsafasfsf You're missing `END` in all those `CASE`s.

Answer (score 2):

This is as close as I could get formatting this into something more legible. I converted to ANSI-92 style join syntax. I also simplified several pieces. Those calculations are a serious challenge. So many functions going on in there. Surely this could be made simpler but I just can't unravel all of what is going on in there without some serious effort. This is by no means a perfect solution but at least it is a lot cleaner and the syntax is at least valid now.

```
SELECT ib.cli_no
    , c.cli_name
    , sum
        ( 
            case 
                when isnull(ib.sell_price, 0) <= 0.0 
                        or isnull(ib.retail_price, 0) <= 0 
                        or (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0)) = 0 
                    then 0.0
                when left(p.prod_no, 1) + lower(p.monad) = '3kg' 
                        and (isnull(ib.sell_price, 0) - isnull(ib.retail_price, 0)) > 286
                        and (isnull(ib.sell_price, 0) - isnull(ib.retail_price, 0)) <= 1000 
                    then ib.inv_num * 100 * convert(numeric(12,3), right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(varchar(50),(Square(CEILING(((isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))/100- 0.01)/0.5)+1)+10000)))),4)) 
                when left(p.prod_no,1)='3' and lower(p.monad)='kg' and  (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))>1000 and  (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))<=2000 
                    then  ib.inv_num * 100*convert(numeric(12,3), right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(varchar(50),(Square(CEILING((isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))/100- 10.01)+21)+10000)))),4)) 
                when (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0)) > 0.1 
                        and (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0)) <= 10 
                    then ib.inv_num * convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),Square(CEILING(((isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0) ) - 0.01)/0.5)+1)+10000))),4))
                when (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))>10  and   (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))<=20 
                    then ib.inv_num *convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),Square(CEILING((isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0) ) - 10.01)+21)+10000))),4))
                when (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))>20  and   (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))<=50 
                    then ib.inv_num *convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),(Square(CEILING((isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0) ) - 20.01)/2)+31)+10000))),4))
                when (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))>50  and   (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))<=100 
                    then    ib.inv_num *convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),(Square(CEILING((isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0) ) - 50.01)/3)+46)+10000))),4))
                when (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))>100  and   (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))<=286 
                    then ib.inv_num *convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),(Square(CEILING((isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0) ) - 101.01)/5)+63)+10000))),4))
                when (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))>286  and   (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))<=1366 
                    then ib.inv_num *convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),(Square(CEILING((isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0) ) - 101.01)/5)+63)+100000))),5))
                when (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))> 1366  and   (isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0))<=2000 
                    then ib.inv_num *convert(numeric(12,3),right(rtrim(ltrim(convert(char(50),(Square(CEILING((isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0) ) - 101.01)/5)+63)+1000000))),6))
                else ib.inv_num *isnull(ib.sell_price,0) - isnull(ib.retail_price,0)*60 
            end

        )     
FROM ls_inv_back ib   
join client c on ib.cli_no = c.cli_no
join product p on ib.prod_no = p.prod_no
group by ib.cli_no
    , c.cli_name
```

Comment: Applaudable effort.